# Check whether a specific bit is set in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bit

I have two bytes in:

```
b'T'
```

and

```
b'\x40'     (only bit #6 is set)
```

In need to perform a check on the first byte to see if bit # 6 is set. For example, on [A-Za-9] it would be set, but on all some characters it would not be set.

```
if (b'T' & b'\x40') != 0:
    print("set");
```

does not work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte values, when indexed, give integer values. Use that to your advantage:

```
value = b'T'
if value[0] & 0x40:
    print('set')
```

You cannot use the `&` operator on bytes, but it works just fine on integers.

See the [documentation on the `bytes` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects):

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that `0 <= x < 256`[.]
>
> …
>
> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object `b`, `b[0]` will be an integer[.]

Note that non-zero numbers always test as true in a boolean context, there is no need to explicitly test for `!= 0` here either.

Comment: -1 I think it's dangerous to suggest someone to take 'advantage' of a language instead of suggesting a future-proof guaranteed way of getting functionality 100% correct in all cases. If you have a valid reason to suggest this, I look forward to that reasoning and perhaps will retract my -1 if it sounds reasonable. For those reading this, please go with the answer by @zwol ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/20636521/4726668 ).

Comment: @ZeZNiQ the bytes type **is designed that way**. This is future proof, not a side effect. I’ve added a link to the documentation that covers this.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) built-in function, which converts single-character strings (byte or unicode) to the corresponding numeric codepoint.

```
if ord(b'T') & 0x40:
   print("set")
```