# Numpy: check whether a bit is set to 1 or 0 in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation, bit, bitstring

Suppose the following:

```
bitstring = numpy.random.random_integers(0,2**32,size=8).astype(numpy.uint32)
```

How can I find out which of the 256 bits are set to 1?  I've got this... but this is crazy, isn't it?

```
maximum = (2**32)-1
for checkbit in range (256):
    yes = bool(numpy.bitwise_and((2**checkbit)%maximum, bitstring[  (  (checkbit // maximum) + checkbit % maximum ) // 32  ] ) )
    print 'bit', checkbit, 'set to', yes, 'in string', (  (checkbit // maximum) + checkbit % maximum ) // 32
```

I believe the answer may be extremely simple, yet google hasn't helped at all, and [this related question is referring only to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636467/check-whether-a-specific-bit-is-set-in-python-3).

Since I need to do this op billions of times, I wonder if there's a pythonic way to make it work as fast as possible.

Comment: "which of the 256 bits are set to 1" You are using numbers up to 2**32, that's 32 bits. When you talk of 256 bits, I'm getting more the impression you mean 8-bit numbers, which go up to 256 (unsigned). Which do you mean?

Comment: The first line of code...  it's a bistring, which is an array of uint32 with 8 positions.. hence my 256 bits.

Comment: Ah, understood now. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to count the number of "1" bits or to check wether a specific bit is set.

To check, I guess the easier way is: `bool(n&(1<<b))`, where `n` is the number being tested and `b` is the bit (starting from 0).

To count the number of "1" bit, I guess there is nothing faster than a lookup table.
For instance, you can use 65k of memory and split the 256 bits into 16 groups of 16 bits. Then, you look up in a table the value of the counter.

In order to generate the table, you can use any of the other mentioned methods. For instance:

```
table = [bin(i).count('1') for i in xrange(1<<16)]
```

Then, to count the number of bits, you can just sum up the values form the table, for instance:

```
n = 0x123456789123456789
cnt = 0
while n > 0:
    cnt += table[n%((1<<16)-1)]
    n >>= 16
```

If you have enough memory, you can increase your table. For a 32 bit table you will need 4GB of memory. It is the classical tradeoff of processing vs memory consumption.

Comment: bitshift!  Of course!  I'll do some performance benchmarking...   

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[np.unpackbits`][1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html), although you will first have to view your array as `np.uint8`, and take care your self of figuring how the endianess of your system affects the result you get:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(bitstring.view(np.uint8))
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: I'll check it out and so some benchmarking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a number in python to a binary string with `bin`

```
n = 4187390046
binary_str = bin(n)
```

Which yields

```
Out[7]: '0b11111001100101101000000001011110'
```

Then you can find all indexes of 1 in that string with something like

```
def find_ones(s):
    return [i - 2 for i, bit in enumerate(s) if bit == '1']
```

Because the binary string has the leading `0b` you should adjust the values accordingly

Comment: Thank you. I'll do some performance benchmarking and return here with some results afterwards.